# Why does Gmail keep "forgetting" my POP3 password when it checks a third-party account?

Tags: passwords, gmail, pop3

I have a Gmail account that's configured to check a third-party POP3 account located on another server. Every few days (apparently) Gmail stops checking mail from the POP3 account and reports that the other server dropped the connection. Rechecking for mail fails with the same error. To get around it, I have to edit the account settings within Gmail to reset the POP3 account's password (not changing the password on the POP3 server, just resetting what Gmail thinks it is). After this reset, Gmail correctly logs in and downloads messages for awhile.  This might be a day, but I've seen it happen within an hour as well.

Any idea why Gmail might be periodically "forgetting" the password? Or is it simply a bad error message and resetting the password coincidentally clears a flag within Gmail that allows it to re-try?

ADDITIONAL INFO: The POP3 server in question is running hMailServer hMailServer v5.3.3-B1879

Answer (score 1):

before i remember that this feature has 30 days expire date.

Did it message it to you, when config it?

Another guess is that your server config for POP3 clients that if they refresh more than for example 4 times, then block it, and when you reconfigure another IP in Gmail check that.

Please Contact with your host administrator